# Using socket.io in routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I use socket.io between my angular app and my server without any trouble but I don't know how to do it when it comes to use socket.io in my routes.

Here is what i did so far :

## app.js

```
var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('server',function(data){
    log.info(data.message);
});
socket.on('console',function(data){
    log.info(data.message);
});
socket.emit('client',{action:"test"});
});
```

as i said , it works.

Now i want to use socket.io in one of my routes , routes loaded from my router :

```
require('./app/my.routes')(app,io);//i've tried to use it this way
```

## my.routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app,io){ 
    io = app.get('io');//and get it this way
    io.sockets.emit('socket.io :: sucessfully passed from app to router')
    log.info('Trying to load express routes...');
    router.use(function (req, res, next) {
        next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
    });
    require('./models.mongoose/user');
    //require routes
    var consoleRoute = require('./express.routes/console.route')
   ...
```

and now I have that error

```
io.sockets.emit('socket.io :: sucessfully passed from app to router')
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined
```

I must do something wrong obviously but I have no idea what.
Any ideas ?

I also tried 
    app.set('io',io)
in app.js and
    app.get('io')
on the other side but it failed all the same

## SOLUTION

Finally , i've found the solution,

```
app.io = io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('server', function (data) {
    log.info(data);
});
socket.emit('client', {
    action: "alert",
    text: 'test from socket io'
  });
});;
```

Now it's linked to app, and I can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup your socket io implementation in your express configuration file and pass your "io" object as a variable within the app.

```
app.io = io;
```

the idea is to do something like this:

```
module.exports = function (app){ 
    app.io.sockets.emit('socket.io sucessfully passed from app to router');
}
```

Comment: do you mean : app.io = io in my app.js and then var x = require(somefile)(app,io) so i can use it in somefile like io.emit(....) ?

Comment: Just pass the app since it alteady will have the io object referenced like require("routes")(app)

Comment: ok now , there is no more error but it's completely silent, like nothing happens.weird.I will continue to investigate.

Comment: test if you got it working (in the server) probably you have another issue in the client look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719155/node-js-socket-io-io-emit-doing-nothing

Comment: thanks to you , i have found the solution.post edited